# Where is the Registry running

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I can create a container running a registry: docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2

But docker has a default registry, I can see that the registry is at `Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/` and it must be local, but where is it - do you know?

It is correct that if using a browser and go to: `https://index.docker.io/v1/` it will take you to docker hub: https://index.docker.io/v1/

But all my local images is local on my machine, so there must be some where the registry is running.

You can see the registry if you do:

```
docker system info
Containers: 32
 Running: 29
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 3
Images: 205
Server Version: 18.06.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: d64c661f1d51c48782c9cec8fda7604785f93587
runc version: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.93-linuxkit-aufs
Operating System: Docker for Mac
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 2.934GiB
Name: linuxkit-025000000001
ID: Q6IO:V5CP:OHJL:4KJP:ZG2X:GV5W:YHMM:2WCK:4V4O:O6T3:A4E4:BJHM
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 206
 Goroutines: 223
 System Time: 2018-08-29T11:56:34.8224409Z
 EventsListeners: 2
HTTP Proxy: gateway.docker.internal:3128
HTTPS Proxy: gateway.docker.internal:3129
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the default registry which is dockerhub:

https://hub.docker.com/

Also see:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7203

You cannot change the default registry (which is dockerhub). What you can do is push and pull using your registry as a prefix.

For example:

```
docker push localhost:5000/yourimage

docker pull localhost:5000/yourimage
```

As per my comment below - this registry runs locally and with

```
docker ps | grep registry:2
```

you can see it running. You can then use it's id to get the logs where you will see the activity.

You can also make use of the api by doing a call to:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
```

This will list all the images you have pushed to your local registry.

Comment: Thanks updated the question: Thanks, but there must be a local registry running where the "docker images" is?

Comment: @ChrisG. Might the last paragraph in my answer(local disk storage part) be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

#### Docker has two ways to store images:

- remote registry(docker.io as default, other private ones as
  configured manually)
- local disk(/var/lib/docker/image as default, could be configured with -g flag)

Docker daemon uses image name(i.e. `10.10.100.30:80/public/ubuntu:18.04`) for parsing to figure in which registry and repository it should search.
But docker daemon would check if the image exists on local disk first before search it remotely in a registry. This part may be the most confusion you are suffering.
Please read more information below.

#### Default registry: docker.io

As people said, it could not be overwritten by configuration. Maybe it for safety concern or not.

#### User-defined private registry

I’m quite sure that we could define our own private registry for docker images. After deploying a registry, which should be easy to achieve, all we need to do is configuring the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json`(create it if not exists) with `{“insecure-registries”: [“10.10.100.30:80”]}`.

Of course we should restart docker daemon after configuration. Execute `systemctl restart docker`. If you have username/password set with this registry, you should do login operation. Executing `docker login 10.10.100.30:80`, then input username & password. You may see successful login message if no error occurred.
Now, try type `docker info`, you may see message like below:

```
Insecure Registries:
10.10.100.30:80
127.0.0.0/8
```

Finally, you may push/pull images with private registry url prefix, i.e. `10.10.100.30:80/public/ubuntu:18.04`.

### Local disk storage

This is where `docker images`'s output locate.

There are two perspectives to understand how images are stored on local disk:

1. From human being/filesystem on OS, meaning file & directory(only my
   opinion)

   The default directory is `/var/lib/docker/image/<Storage Driver>`(
   shown with Storage Driver in the output of `docker info`). Next,
   there are several directories(distribution/imagedb/layerdb) and a
   file named `repositories.json`.  This should be the most important
   file within `docker images` operation.
2. From docker daemon

   Multiple layers consisted of an image. When we execute `docker
   build` with Dockerfile, each executive will lead to generate a layer
   by docker daemon. And the same layer could be shared among images.
   So Docker daemon maintains a graph-based database  to manage the
   relationships among those image layers —
   parents/children/lower/upper...

Every time you execute a docker command involving docker image(s), docker daemon will check its own graph-based database first. If not found, execute `docker pull` automatically and store the image information into database to speed future operations.

Since I am still new with Docker too,  I think you may take a look of Docs on docker.com. It’s rather detailed.

May this help~